# Poisson Process question, why's my answer wrong?

Tags: probability

```
At a checkout counter customers arrive according to a Poisson Process 
at the rate of 1.5 customers per minute. Find the probability that at 
most 4 customers arrive in one minute?
```

What I did was (1.5)^4 * e^-1.5 / 4! = `.04706`

But it's wrong.

All my textbook has as answer is `poissoncdf(1.5, 4) = .9814`.

Why's my answer wrong?  I thought I used the formula correctly?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say $X$ is the number of customers that arrive per minute. Then you worked out $$P(X=4)$$ but the question is actually asking you to work out $$P(X\le4)$$ You can do this in one of two ways:

1) $$P(X\le4)=P(X=0)+P(X=1)+P(X=2)+P(X=3)+P(X=4)$$
2) Use some Poisson tables to find this probability.

Comment: Thanks a lot man :D!  Makes total sense!

Comment: No problem! :-)